# Replace consecutive identical row occurences to single row based on same Id - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to reduce the **consecutive** identical rows within the same Id to one single row. I tried duplication but then it replaces all non-consecutive identical occurrences within the same Id to one single row. Also, the order of the message is important. The input and the desired output is shown below. Is there any way to achieve this desired result?

Thanks

Input data

```
Id   Result   Message
----------------------
1     0        a 
1     0        p 
1     0        p
1     0        p
1     0        d
1     0        p 
1     0        p 
1     0        f
1     0        p
2     1        a
2     1        a
2     1        a
2     1        f
2     1        h
2     1        b
2     1        b
3     0        d
3     0        d
3     0        d
3     0        c
3     0        c
```

Desired output

```
Id   Result   Message
----------------------
1     0        a 
1     0        p 
1     0        d
1     0        p  
1     0        f
1     0        p
2     1        a
2     1        f
2     1        h
2     1        b
3     0        d
3     0        c
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to the rows, unless a column specifies the ordering.  You should fix the question to include such a column.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @GordonLinoff's comment into consideration, if you were to include a column which specified the order in which you wanted the rows looked at, for example,

```
Id   Result   Message   Order
1     0        a         1
1     0        p         2 
1     0        p         2
1     0        p         2
1     0        d         3
1     0        p         4
1     0        p         4
1     0        f         5
1     0        p         6
2     1        a         7
2     1        a         7
2     1        a         7
2     1        f         8
2     1        h         9
2     1        b        10
2     1        b        10
3     0        d        11
3     0        d        11
3     0        d        11
3     0        c        12
3     0        c        12
```

Then you could easily obtain the desired result with the following query:

```
SELECT distinct Id, Result, Message, Order
FROM Table_A
```

OUPUT:

```
Id   Result   Message   Order
1     0        a         1
1     0        p         2 
1     0        d         3
1     0        p         4
1     0        f         5
1     0        p         6
2     1        a         7
2     1        f         8
2     1        h         9
2     1        b        10
3     0        d        11
3     0        c        12
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But for me, it is not possible to include an additional column 'order' and populate it manually. Since I am new to SQL, I would like to know if there is any query which populates the 'Order' column by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for Group by?

SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3;

The order of the result will be the order of the columns you pass.